# View binding is not working in multiple modules

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I am adding view binding to my project, and it works fine when I use it in the first module by adding the following to my module-level build.gradle:

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

When I enable view binding in the `build.gradle` file of a second module, the binding class is found in Android Studio and works with code completion, but when I build I get an error:

```
error: package mypackage.databinding does not exist
import mypackage.databinding.MyLayoutBinding;
```

How can I get it to work in the second module?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was resolved by updating my build tools version from 3.6.0 to 3.6.1.